# Rendering out of place in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rendering

How can i render an asp.net page in an order that i want. For example, in this Stackoverflow page you have Questions, Tags, users, Badges, Unanswered, ... at the top and then the question heading and the answers. If you view source for this, you will find that Questions, Tags are rendered from line 76, onwards. While the Question details start from line 97.

What if i want to have the Question details ( Main Content ) to start before line 76 in source ( Before the menu / header ).

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

That's just a matter of styling/layout, which you control via CSS. Depending on the layout model you choose, you can render the items anywhere in the HTML, and put them anywhere you like visually.

-- Edit:

To provide slightly more details, you can use 'positioning' layouts, or floats, or tables (considered bad for layout-only purposes) or some combination thereof. A great website to learn about this, and the best ways to to it, regarding compatibility is [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/). Some other people may reply with better sites.